# Quickblox login facebook Android

Tags: java, quickblox

I search many on stackoverflow but don't get answer yet.

```
 loginButtonFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, facebookAccessToken, null, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final QBUser user, Bundle args) {
                    ChatService.getInstance().login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {......................}
```

and it gets error:

> Token is required

Can anyone give me some method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add this before signIn:

```
facebookAccessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
```

This way you sign in using the facebook session. Hope it helps !

Answer (score -1):

```
enter code here
AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
String fb_token=token.getToken();
```

After logging in through facebook Successfully put the following code to get the current access token of the user

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just providing a code-snippet.